# Call to undefined method Posts::newQuery()

Tags: php, laravel

Why am I getting this error? And how can I solve this one? I'm trying to retrieve a post of a user.

**User.php model**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function Posts()
    {
            return $this->hasMany('Posts');
    }
}
```

**Post.php model**

```
<?php 

    Class Posts extends Eloquent 
    {
        public function User()
        {
                return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }
```

}

The error, I guess, is in `Posts.php` model.

**Controller**

```
public function newPost($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $post =  new Posts();
        $post->title = Input::get('title');
        $post->content = nl2br(Input::get('content'));

        $user->post()->save($post);

        return Redirect::route('profile', array('id' => $user->id));

    }
```

**View**

```
@section('post')
    <section>
        @foreach($users->posts as $post)
        <p>{{$user->name}} says...</p>
        <blockquote>{{$post->content}}</blockquote>
        @endforeach
    </section>
        
@stop
```

Comment: There should be hint in your error message in which line of which file the error occurred. I cannot find newQuery in your given code here.

Comment: return new HasMany($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
 }
  i guess this is it?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses a lot of convention over configuration, so make sure your conventions are correct.

If your class is `Posts`, make sure your file is named `Posts.php`. Your question has it mentioned both ways.

Your relationship method on the user is `Post()` (capitalized), but you're accessing it as `$user->post()` (lowercase). Make sure your naming and usage is consistent.